# Form PDE whose general solution is $z=Ae^{-p^2t}\cos px$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

$$z=Ae^{-p^2t}\cos px$$

Came across an exercise requesting that the PDE with the above general solution should be formed.

My approach was to find the following partial differentials:

$z_x, z_{xx}, z_t, z_{tt} $

Comparing their values I got the following PDEs:

$$z_t-z_{xx}=0$$

$$z_{tt}+p^2z_{xx}=0$$

$$z_t+p^2z=0$$

$$z_{tt}-p^4z=0$$

Then it dawned on me that perhaps only the second PDE is correct as it has almost all the parameters given in the original general solution.

Please are all the four PDEs I provided right? Or is it just the second PDE? Are there other possible PDEs?

Comment: I think equation of damped oscillation also has same solution

Comment: @ArchisWelankar you mean this: $z_{tt}+2p^2z_t+p^4z=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution of a second order PDE with 2 variables $x$ and $t$ involves two arbitrary functions of $x$ and $t$. So, $z=Ae^{-p^2t}\cos px$ cannot be the general solution because they are two arbitrary constant, but no arbitrary function.

I think that there is something fishy in the wording of the question, or something missing.

If it is requested that $z=Ae^{-p^2t}\cos px$ be a particular family of solutions any $A$ and $p$, but not the general solution, the related PDE must be invariant any $A$ and $p$. So, those parameters must not appear into it. Thus the simplest PDE should be :
$$z_t-z_{xx}=0$$

Comment: I agree, there is something fishy in the wording of the question